# Using grep command, I can print the data that match with my command but how to print an error when data is not available?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have device.json file available in my subdirectories and from that .json file, I am trying to print data = xxx value and I am using following Grep command but I also wanted to print an error when device.json file is not available in one of the subdirectory.

find . -name "device.json" | xargs grep -E 'data'

Comment: So what do you see when it's not available? :)

Comment: So based on above command, If subdirectory have device.json file available with data=xxx then it prints all the subdirectories names along with data = xxx values and I also want to print those subdirectories names which doesn't have this device.json file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about directories that do not contain a "device.json" entry, then `find . -name device.json` is not going to cut it.  You'll have to do something like:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'for x; do f="$x/device.json"; if test -f "$f"; 
    then grep -H data "$f"; else echo "$f: No such file" >&2; fi; done' _ {} \+
```

Comment: `date` should be changed into `data` ;-)

Comment: `echo $f...` -> `echo "$f..."` in case any directory name contains blanks or globbing chars.

Comment: copy and pasting this command shows an error like, find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

Comment: @KD228 Perhaps you are copy-pasting into a csh family shell, and it is not allowing the single quoted string to encapsulate the newline.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
find . -type d |
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    file="$dir/device.json"
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        grep 'data' "$file"
    else
        printf '"%s" does not exist\n' "$file"
    fi
done
```

It'll only fail if your directory names can contain newlines. Obviously `grep 'data'` is not a robust way to find the value you want in a json file but that's a separate issue.